# Regex for alphanumeric with at least 6 alphabet(non space) and 1 numeric

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I want to allow users to fill password with at least 7 character(no limit) that must have 1 numeric and 6 alphabet.

Comment: You should think about using zxcvbn. Google it.

Comment: at least one numeric right?

Comment: I believe a key requirement is that of the minimum 7 characters, 6 must be alphabetic so that, for example, "pass1234" would not match.  So I don't agree that this is a duplicate of the other questions referenced. Here is a solution that works for me:  ^(?=(.*[A-Za-z]){6})(?=[A-Za-z]*\d)[A-Za-z0-9]{7,}$

Comment: I don't know why this marked as duplicate, anyways thanks a lot @Anthony, you understand my requirement exactly what I need and saved my time. This exactly works for me. Thanks once again!

Answer (score 0):

```
/^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$/
```

this is regex for atleast 1 digit in password